# Select / dropdown inner-border in Firefox 24 Aurora when focus

Tags: css, cross-browser

In the new Firefox Aurora seems to be really difficult to remove the inner-border when focus on a **select** element

I have created a codepen to check it. The thing is that it works in all the browser but in the new FF.

The CSS for the select is:

```
select:focus,
select:active,
option:focus,
option:active{
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
           box-shadow: none;
   outline: 0px none transparent;
}
select::-moz-focus-inner{
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
           box-shadow: none;
   outline: 0px none transparent;  
}
```

Here is the http://codepen.io/rafamacias/pen/GuzKg)

Do you know how to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

select:-moz-focusring {color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;}